# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.config' has no attribute 'run_functions_eagerly'

Tags: python, jupyter, imageai

Trying to run ImageAI in Jupyter.
I'm getting the following error

### ***Using TensorFlow backend.***

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 from imageai.Detection.Custom import DetectionModelTrainer

~\anaconda3\envs\ImageAI\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\Custom_*init*_.py in 
19 import cv2
20
---> 21 tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
22 os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
23

~\anaconda3\envs\ImageAI\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\module_wrapper.py in **getattr**(self, name)
191   def **getattr**(self, name):
192     try:
--> 193       attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
194     except AttributeError:
195       if not self._tfmw_public_apis:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.config' has no attribute 'run_functions_eagerly

What is the issue here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
@tf.function
def fn():
  # `enter code here
```